# Why am I getting this message when setting up membership payment page?

Tags: civimember

Using 4.6.8 I have a monthly membership that is not auto-renew, and I am using a payment processor that supports recurring payments (Go Cardless for UK direct debit). Now I want to set up a membership payment page.  In the 'Amounts' section I checked 'recurring contributions' but when I tried to save I get the message "You cannot enable both Recurring Contributions and Auto-renew memberships on the same online contribution page."
Which isn't helpful as the membership isn't auto-renew.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this because the auto-renew function on the Membership tab takes care of the recurring payment, so you don't need to also enable recurring Contributions? Does the [Manual](http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/membership/online-membership-sign-up/) help clarify this for you?

Comment: I managed to get round this problem by entering the data in the tabs in strict sequence and knowing what to enter (!), which avoided the problem.

Comment: well if my answer didn't really help it would be good if you could post your comment with a bit more info, as an answer and then vote for it your self. just keeps stackexchange happy that questions do get answers that get accepted ;-)

Comment: Your answer was helpful, thanks, but like everything (it seems) the solution to get this working is more complicated.  We're using a UK direct debit extension which doesn't seem to work with membership contribution pages. However, there does seem to be a problem with configuring membership contrib screens if you do them out of order as I did.  You can't do 'A' unless you do something in 'B' and vice versa, so you're stuck.  But do them in order and you're OK.

Comment: Hi Andy,

Are you saying the uk direct debit module just won't work with memberships?

Or, that it will work with a membership contribution page but you have to follow the exact steps in set up?

I've just installed UK Direct Debit with Smart Debit extensions and am trying to configure a membership contribution page.

Any advice you can give would be appreciated.

Cheers,

Craig

Comment: very keen to hear back from Craig or Andy on this. Does GoCardless work for memberships?

Comment: Forked this over to a specific question re gocardless and memberships - http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/12319/can-gocardless-be-used-for-auto-renew-memberships - appreciate your input if you can add anything.